# React component to render markdown with code highlight

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown

I need to create a documentation component that renders .md files.

I have a collection of .md files (that could potentially be stored in a DB instead of having files) and I would like to allow users do navigate the documentation and see articles.

About rendering the files I've tried most of the stuff the Google has listed am currently, I am experimenting with the component [react-markdown](https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown).

I'm having trouble figuring out the code highlight peace and I was wondering if there is a component out there, that does that out of the box or that have it as a straight boolean option.

`<ReactMarkdown source={file}/>`

**note:** I've checked the answer in [How do I render Markdown from a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31875748/how-do-i-render-markdown-from-a-react-component) and couldn't find a good one.

Comment: have you made any progress on this? I've been fondling this sort of thing for a few days now with little to no success. I can't seem to load my markdown from an external file. I was going to post my own question but thought I'd shoot you a comment and see if you've had any success. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the issue by using [React Syntax Highlighter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-syntax-highlighter) and passing it into React Markdown's `renderers` attribute. It has a support for [Prism.js](https://prismjs.com) and [Highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org) syntax highlighter libraries.

Have been searching for the solution for a while, and wrote a blog post on solving the particular problem. [Check it out!](https://medium.com/young-developer/react-markdown-code-and-syntax-highlighting-632d2f9b4ada)