# Converting markdown text into React components

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, markdown

I am using an npm package called **react-markdown** to convert a piece of markdown text into HTML code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';

let body = '## Some markdown text in multiple paragraphs';

class Post extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    <ReactMarkdown source={body} />
  }
}

export default Post;
```

This works fine except individual paragraphs are rendered with the standard `<p>` tags. In my use-case, I need them rendered as custom components, say, `<MyParagraph>`. In other words, consider the following input text:

```
This is paragraph one.

Lorem ipsum doler sit.

This is paragraph two.
```

**react-markdown** renders the markdown as:

```
<p>This is paragraph one.</p>

<p>Lorem ipsum doler sit.</p>

<p>This is paragraph two.</p>
```

And I need it as:

```
<MyParagraph>This is paragraph one.</MyParagraph>

<MyParagraph>Lorem ipsum doler sit.</MyParagraph>

<MyParagraph>This is paragraph two.</MyParagraph>
```

Is it even possible with this module? Or should I use something else?

Comment: **See Also**: [How do I render Markdown from a React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31875748/1366033)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this: https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown/issues/218

The `renderers` property is helpful to create custom component.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import ReactMarkdown from "react-markdown";

let body =
  "## Some markdown text in multiple paragraphs\n\nAnd this is a paragraph 1\n\nAnd this is a paragraph 2\n\nAnd this is a paragraph 3";

const MyParagraph = props => (
  <p>This is inside MyParagraph, and the value is {props.children}</p>
);

// see https://github.com/rexxars/react-markdown#node-types
const renderers = {
  paragraph: props => <MyParagraph {...props} />
};

class Post extends PureComponent {
  render() {
    return <ReactMarkdown source={body} renderers={renderers} />;
  }
}

export default Post;

ReactDOM.render(<Post />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the codesandbox of above code: https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-surf-r05kb?fontsize=14